# Telerik Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, telerik-reporting

i have a MVC project, i try to add Telerik Reporting Services inside.

I have added this references

```
Telerik.Reporting
Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi
Telerik.Reporting.XpsRendering
Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc
```

Also, in my WepApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

       // config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(config);
    }
}
```

And when i run my project i get this exception

```
Method not found: 'Void Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes
```

Has anyone a clue about what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error is that The Reporting REST WebAPI Service is built against WebAPI **1**.

And in your case you are using a newer version (WebAPI **2**).

So, you have to redirect the **System.Web.Http** and **System.Net.Http.Formatting** to their newer version.

To do this, add the following **bindingRedirects** to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and replace

> 5.2.3.0

with your current version, as 5.2.3.0 is currently the most recent one.

and if your web.config already contains the  section, just append the  nodes to it.

[taken from this article](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-host-http-service-using-web-hosting)